# Can you help me recover my accidentally deleted videos?

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, linux, device-firmware, android-10

I have a Nokia 2.2 smartphone runnig Android 10 ( a hateful piece of software from my opinion). From 16 GB of storage only 2 are available for the user and it's shrinking even more with every new update. That's why I have disabled auto update and installed a sd-card in storage expansion mode (the phone uses the sd card as the internal memory).

I've been gone on a trip and took some videos and photos with the phone since I ran out of memory on my compact camera. On the way home, out of pure dumbness I deleted the DCIM folder.

"Fine, I will just install a recovery app." Guess what? Those require root and the Android 10 system is not vulnerable to any root exploits that I know. And Nokia will not allow me to unlock my bootloader!

"Ok. I will take the card out, plug it on my computer and start recuva from piriform." It didn't work. Windows is unable to open the card, but it shows it on device manager as 2 "healthy" partitions. "Maybe it is an ext4 file system and it will mount just fine on my linux laptop (Q4S Trinity desktop based on debian)" That one doesn't even detect that I've connected the card! The only device that is able to read the card is my phone! What can I do? Is there any way that I can  get my videos back? A firmware dump? How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When mounting the sd-card as internal storage the sd-card is encrypted and can be read nowhere except from the phone it has been initialized in. Therefore removing the card and running recovery tools on it is totally useless as it will not work.

Comment: try this app it may recover pictures from thumbnails and trash folders https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free

Comment: Damn! Thanks aniway bro.